# JMockit and Jersey JAX-RS Testing

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, jersey, jmockit

I have a Jersey REST webservice which I want to build a unit test, I followed the steps provided by Jersey Test documentation, but in my webservice I have references to additional classes which handles the business logic of the flow, I am trying to use JMockit to mock the business service class that is referenced by the service but I get errors:

ProdService is my RESTful JAX-RS webservice.
ProdServiceBusinessRemote is my Business service interface which is injected into ProdService and does business logic processing.
I want to mock ProdServiceBusinessRemote inside ProdServiceTest:

```
public class ProdServiceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Injectable
    private ProdServiceBusinessRemote prodServiceBusinessRemote;

    @Before 
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initMocks(); 
    }

    private void initMocks() throws Exception {
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            prodServiceBusinessRemote.query();
            result = null;          
        }};

    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(ProdService.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        List list = target("prod").request().get(List.class);
        org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(list == null);
    }
}
```

If I run without the @RunWith(JMockit.class)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JMockit wasn't properly initialized; please ensure that jmockit precedes junit in the runtime classpath, or use @RunWith(JMockit.class)
```

If I run with @RunWith(JMockit.class) I get an NullPointerException inside JerseyTest internal function:

```
public final WebTarget target() {
    return client().target(getTestContainer().getBaseUri());
}
```

where client() is null;

Is there a way to use Jmockit and JerseyTest together ? How does Jersey recommend in the case of Services which references external classes? How to mock these ones?

Comment: What is `ProdServiceBusinessRemote` and how is it being used? Is it supposed to be injected into `ProductService`? Also one thing to note about `@Before` is that JerseyTest also implements a `@Before` and superclass "befores" are called before subclass. JerseyTest's "before" creates the application, so it's to late to do any application initialization in out "before" You can do any initialization in the `configure` method though, as it's called for each test case.

Comment: @peeskillet 
ProdService is my RESTful JAX-RS webservice.
ProdServiceBusinessRemote is my Business service interface which is injected into ProdService and does business logic processing.
I want to mock ProdServiceBusinessRemote inside ProdServiceTest using JMockit. Otherwise is there a standard, Jersey way of doing the mocking ?

Comment: How are you currently injecting that service into the main application? Is it through HK2? Normally I will just bind the mocked service with HK2, and register the binder with the ResourceConfig, in the test. Sometimes if it's a small test of the resource class only has one service to inject, I'll just instantiate the resource and assign the mocked service. Of course the service field would need to be package private, and the test class in the same package as the resource class (of course one in src/main and one in src/test), this is testing convention.

Comment: @peeskillet I'm injecting the service using EJB annotation in my rest API class

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to do the following changes:

1. Make sure jmockit jar is being loaded before junit in pom.xml:

   ```
       <!-- ************ TEST DEPENDENCIES ************ -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId> 
          <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId> 
          <version>${jmockit.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>${junit.version}</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   ```
2. Don't annotate your test class with @RunWith(JMockit.class) and make sure you have all extra maven dependencies for jersey test:

   ```
       <!-- ************** Jersey Test ************************ -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
           <version>${org.glassfish.jersey.core.version}</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   ```
3. Your test class needs to extend JerseyTest. So avoid using @Before and @After annotations.
4. Sample class to be tested:

   @Path("/offer")

   ```
   public class OfferService extends BaseWebService {

   @EJB(mappedName = "myapp/OfferServiceBean")
   private OfferServiceBeanLocal offerServiceBean;
   public OfferServiceBeanLocal getServiceBean() {
       return offerServiceBean;
   }
   public void setOfferServiceBean(OfferServiceBeanLocal offerServiceBean) {
       this.offerServiceBean = offerServiceBean;
   }
   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
   @Path("/offers") 
   public ListResponseDto<OfferDto> searchOffers(@Valid ListRequest v) {

           ListResponseDto<OfferDto> list = null;              
           try {           
               list = getServiceBean().getSellerOfferList(v);         
           } catch(Exception e) {
               logException(e);
           }      
           return list;      
   }
   ```

   }
5. Test class for OfferService:

   public class OfferServiceTest extends JerseyTest {

   ```
   @Mocked
   private HttpServletRequest request;

   @Mocked 
   private HttpServletResponse response;

   @Override
   protected Application configure() {
       enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
       enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);

       OfferService service = new OfferService();

       // inject a Mocked EJB instance into your resource class
       service.setOfferServiceBean(new OfferServiceBeanMock());
       ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
       config.register(service);        
       return config;
   }

   @Test
   public void test() throws Exception {
       // mocking static singleton example:
       new MockUp<ConfigurationManager>()
       {
           @Mock
           ConfigurationManager getInstance()
           {
               return MockWebTestUtil.buildConfigurationManagerMock(); 
           }
       };
       String expectedText = "{\"list\":[{\"id\":\"0\",\"name\":\"offer_0\"price\":0},{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"offer_1\",\"price\":1}],\"summary\":{\"params\":null,\"page\":1,\"pageCount\":1,\"totalCount\":2},\"status\":{\"statusCode\":\"SUCCESS\",\"statusMessage\":null}}";

       ListRequest l = new ListRequest();
       l.setPage(1);
       l.setSearchColumns(new ArrayList<>());
       l.setRowsPerPage(10);

       Response output = target("/offer/offers").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(l));       
       Assert.assertTrue(output.getStatus() == HttpStatus.OK_200);             
       Assert.assertTrue(output.getHeaders().get("Content-Type").get(0).equals("application/json"));
       String textBody = output.readEntity(String.class);              
       Assert.assertTrue(textBody.equals(expectedText));
   }
   ```

   }

   class OfferServiceBeanMock implements OfferServiceBeanLocal {

   ```
   @Override
   public ListResponseDto<OfferDto> getSellerOfferList(ListRequest v) throws ServiceException {        
       OfferListResponse resp = null;
       try {
           // build 2 sample offers
           resp = MockWebTestUtil.buildOfferListResponseDto(2);                
       } catch (Exception e) {}
       return resp;
   }
   ```

   }